# How to debug USB devices on an Ubuntu 18

Tags: linux, ubuntu, usb, thunderbolt

How can I debug USB devices on my Ubuntu Linux?

#### Hardware

I've got a Cherry keyboard connected by USB to a dell thunderbolt docking station which is itself connected to a XPS 15.

#### Problem Description

Most of the time, everything works fine. But after lets say half an hour/an hour, the laptop does not respond to any key ups/downs, but eg. NUM-LED on the keyboard is on - which at least means it doesn't lose power. If I remove the keyboard and reconnect it, everything works fine again. (I have the same problem with my Mouse, but let's stick with the keyboard first).

In a second situation - the main part of the keyboard works fine (chars, nums, f1-12) - it apparently (also after an hour or so) loses track of additional keys like "next song" or "play/pause".

Edit:

The prevous situation is in the Office. I do have the same problem with my Mouse at home. Same constellation as described above.
If I connect the mouse/keyboard directly to the laptop, I don't have those problems.

Edit 2:

`dmesg` log: 
Keyboard stopped after following error:

```
[ 5790.001573] [drm:intel_pipe_update_end [i915]] *ERROR* Atomic update failure on pipe C (start=306772 end=306773) time 348 us, min 1073, max 1079, scanline start 1068, end 1092
```

Now reconnecting the keyboard:

```
[ 6062.306791] usb 3-1.3: USB disconnect, device number 3
[ 6065.344687] usb 3-1.3: new low-speed USB device number 6 using xhci_hcd
[ 6065.518026] usb 3-1.3: New USB device found, idVendor=046a, idProduct=0180
[ 6065.518031] usb 3-1.3: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
[ 6065.518035] usb 3-1.3: Product: wired keyboard
[ 6065.518037] usb 3-1.3: Manufacturer:  
[ 6065.554973] input:   wired keyboard as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1b.0/0000:02:00.0/0000:03:01.0/0000:05:00.0/0000:06:04.0/0000:08:00.0/0000:09:01.0/0000:0a:00.0/usb3/3-1/3-1.3/3-1.3:1.0/0003:046A:0180.0007/input/input32
[ 6065.613916] hid-generic 0003:046A:0180.0007: input,hidraw0: USB HID v1.11 Keyboard [  wired keyboard] on usb-0000:0a:00.0-1.3/input0
[ 6065.628175] input:   wired keyboard as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1b.0/0000:02:00.0/0000:03:01.0/0000:05:00.0/0000:06:04.0/0000:08:00.0/0000:09:01.0/0000:0a:00.0/usb3/3-1/3-1.3/3-1.3:1.1/0003:046A:0180.0008/input/input33
[ 6065.685283] hid-generic 0003:046A:0180.0008: input,hidraw1: USB HID v1.11 Device [  wired keyboard] on usb-0000:0a:00.0-1.3/input1
```

---

Are those two problems in any way connected to each other? Is this a driver problem of the laptop/the docking station? 
And the main question: How can I debug and fix this problem?

Comment: First step is to look in `dmesg` or syslog (via journalctl on systemd) to see if there are any suspicious errors. "Laptop doesn't respond, NUM is on" and "additional keys don't work" make me suspect this is a problem with the keyboard microcontroller, not with USB. As you can't repair the controller, you probably need a new keyboard.

Comment: As I do have a similar situation at home, I updated my question with more information. But I will definetly try your suggestions.